# externally defined function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef void ( * fncptr)(void);
extern void externalfunc(void);

template<void( * test)(void)>
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() { test(); }
};

void localfunc()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
constexpr fncptr alias = localfunc;
extern fncptr externalAlias;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Bar<localfunc> b;
    Bar<alias> b2; // This wouldn't compile if alias wasn't constexpr
    Bar<externalfunc> b3;
//  Bar<externalAlias> b4;

    return 0;
}
```

and external.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void ( * fncptr)(void);

void externalfunc()
{
    std::cout << "Hello external world" << std::endl;
}

fncptr externalAlias = externalfunc;
```

Now the problem is I need something like the 4th line in the main func to work. I get those function declarations from an external C library so I cannot touch those. Currently the 4th line does not compile. gcc 4.6 says "it must be the address of a function with external linkage". In fact it does also say this if you make `alias` not constexpr, so the actual meaning (I think) should be interpreted as: "I don't know for 100% sure the function address you're giving me is constant which I need for instantiating this template". Is there any way around this as i cannot declare `externalalias` as `constexpr` in `main.cpp`?

Before you come with alternate solutions: I am already trying to get this work by just passing the function pointers through the constructor and save them locally but I am still interested if I could get make the template version to work :).

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what the value of `externalAlias` is so that it can instantiate the template?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't know that value of `externalAlias`, but it's a variable and hence it knows the location of that variable at compile-time, so it can template on that. (as seen in another answer (i.e. my answer :-) )).

Comment: Why do you want to do class specialization with a template? That is what inheritance is for. (i.e. test() should just be a pure virtual method of Bar) And then have implementations of test in the derived classes that correspond to the localfunc, alias, externfunc, etc... Or better yet, Bar is just a standalone class and is passed an instance of and "ITest" class in it's constructor. Doing tricky things with templates just results in unmaintainable code for other to inherit.

Comment: @selbie: I do not want to do class specialization, that example was just minimized code to show the problem. The actual problem is in fact a situation where I have 1 kind of resource logic/handling that I need to wrap 3-4 C functions that however have a different function (only name differs, not syntax) for every kind of resource. Currently I was just copy pasting a class for every set of those functions, only replacing class name and the actual functions called, sounds much like manual templating...

Comment: @KillianDS - I figured as much. Still, it sounds like you are doing something extreme with templates when a strategy pattern with virtual methods and interfaces would likely do. On my product team, templates are heavily discouraged - and with good reason - they can be harder to debug and maintain. And usually some applied use of (interface) inheritance would suffice. I apologize for not actually answering your question. But I just wanted to encourage you to think away from templates and towards something more maintainable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: @selbie: That was another alternative I implemented more or less :). The thing is that it is not pure strategy functionality. In fact, the strategy stays the same: create, dosomething, delete. It is only because of ridiculous legacy that there are N number of functions for N types of resources. Your solution and other comparables (e.g. storing the function pointers per object) have a runtime overhead (extra storage or vtables) that I'd rather omit if possible.

Comment: @KillianDS - I think I get the problem now. I'd have to know more to really weigh in further. You know the code better than anyone else. I'll just encourage you to think in terms of interfaces and abstractions so you likely land on the right solution.  Good luck and thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names `alias` and `externAlias` are **not** functions! They are pointers to functions and as such mutable. You cannot use mutable objects as template arguments because the template arguments need to be resolved at compile time. There are two things you can do, however:

1. You can create a wrapper calling the potentially aliased function using whatever name you choose to give the wrapper. This can also conveniently adjust the type if there is some level of difference between the function signatures.
2. You can use a constant pointer to function pointer as template argument: the usual one more level of indirection assumption applies here, too.

All this said, what are you actually trying to achieve? Are you sure you don't just want something like `std::function<void(void)>`? I realize that this is used for type erasure while you seem to have the opposite target and turn function pointers into unique types. However, the way you go about it seems that this isn't really what you intend to do.

Here is an example of how the second option could look like:

```
#include <iostream>

extern void f(int);
extern void g(int);

void (*falias)(int) = f;
void (*galias)(int) = g;

template <void (**alias)(int)>
struct foo
{
    void bar() { (*alias)(17); }
};

void f(int x) { std::cout << "f(x)=" << x << "\n"; }
void g(int x) { std::cout << "g(x)=" << x << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo<&falias>().bar();
    foo<&galias>().bar();
}
```

The fact that `f()` and `g()` end up being implemented in the same translation unit is entirely immaterial: you can move them somewhere else without any problems.

Comment: I am using a library that has a certain callFlow like "createX, doSomethingWithX, deleteX' but with X different for various purposes. As the logic surrounding those calls is identical for all uses, I tried to put this in a single templatized container and pass those 3 function pointers to that template, reducing the need to copy this functionality for each X. The class type should be unique for each X also (due to some statics).

Comment: Why can't you use `&createX`, `&doSomethingWithX`, `&deleteX` in this case? These seem to be functions in the library. If they are not but may be aliases (i.e. called via a function pointer) you will have to create some sort of wrapper. ... or use option 2.

Comment: I tried it doing like your example and it worked for the `localfunc` of my original example but not `externalfunc`. But I'm probably going to go for option 1 and add another wrapper :).

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to have to manually annotate the types a little, this is possible. Ultimately, the types of the various objects are subtly different.

I'll write this answer backwards, looking at `main` first:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Bar<void(*)(void) , localfunc> b;
    Bar<void(**)(void), &alias> b2;
    Bar<void(*)(void) , externalfunc> b3;
    Bar<void(**)(void), &externalAlias> b4;

    return 0;
}
```

You might want to consider `typeof`(g++) or `decltype`(c++11) to create the slightly more readable, and perhaps use a macro:

```
Bar<decltype(&localfunc), localfunc> b;
Bar<decltype(&alias), &alias> b2;
Bar<decltype(&externalfunc), externalfunc> b3;
Bar<decltype(&externalAlias), &externalAlias> b4;
```

I had to change the Bar template a little:

```
template<typename T, T t>
class Bar;
```

so that it can deal with function-pointers and with *pointers*-to-function-pointers. This requires two specializations:

```
template<void( * test)(void)>
class Bar<void(*)(void), test>
{
public:
    Bar() { std::cout << "* "; test(); }
};
template<void( ** test)(void)>
class Bar<void(**)(void), test>
{
public:
    Bar() { std::cout << "**"; (*test)(); }
};
```

It should be possible to add further specializations for other types of function with different parameter types and return types, including even method calls.

I tested this fully on my own machine. Here's a demo (without the external function) on [ideone](http://ideone.com/XKAZO).

Note: With the aliases, the template parameter is the address of the alias, and hence it will take account of any changes that you make to the alias variable at runtime. I guess you'll probably want to make the aliases const. `const fncptr alias = localfunc;`